# javafx.fxml.LoadException and JavaFX SceneBuilder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I create playerMp3. I'm trying to create a GUI in ScenBuilder and import it into my code. I use FXMLoader for this, but I get an error when compiling. In the module-info I have indicated that I use javafx.fxml. I don't know what the error is. I have java 14, JavaFX SceneBuilder 2.0 and the latest InteliJ .

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53833:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p "C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14.0.1\javafx-base-14.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14.0.1\javafx-graphics-14.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\Radek\Desktop\Moje programy\target\classes;C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14.0.1\javafx-graphics-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14.0.1\javafx-base-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\14.0.1\javafx-fxml-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\14.0.1\javafx-fxml-14.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14.0.1\javafx-controls-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Radek\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14.0.1\javafx-controls-14.0.1-win.jar" -m mp3player/com.kulig.mp3player.main.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Radek/Desktop/Moje%20programy/target/classes/fxml/mainPane.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:930)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at mp3player/com.kulig.mp3player.main.Main.start(Main.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fxml.MainPane
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:928)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application com.kulig.mp3player.main.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my pom.xml

```
    <artifactId>mp3player</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.version>14.0.1</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxml.MainPane">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="310.0" text="mp2" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

my module-info

```
module mp3player {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    exports com.kulig.mp3player.main to javafx.graphics;

}
```

and my Main class

```
package com.kulig.mp3player.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane mainPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/mainPane.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Mp3 Player");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The root error is:  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fxml.MainPane`. It's thrown because you have `fx:controller="fxml.MainPane"` but apparently the class `fxml.MainPain` does not exist, at least not from the point of view of the `FXMLLoader`. Are you sure that's the correct fully qualified name? After fixing that, you may have to `opens` the controller's package to at least the `javafx.fxml` module.

Comment: yes, fully qualified name is correct. hint with "fx:controller="fxml.MainPane" was helpful. I cleaned my code in mainPane.fxml,  created a new in ScenBuilder and the override it . Now it is working , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

opens mp3player  to javafx.fxml;
add this line of code at your module-info;